# Review Ban with invisible answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just had my first review ban:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7104150.
>
> Come back in 2 days to continue reviewing.

1. Its just blank... I think I do not have enough rep to actually see the answer that I voted `Looks OK` on. Am I missing something here?? Is this a "feature" or hazing the new guy?
2. From hazy memory - there was enough in the answer to leave it as is. The OP was asking for a plugin, and the answerer was giving a link to a plugin plus some info.

Please enlighten me in the error of my ways, so I can improve my reviewing :)

Comment: it was a spam and deleted so only 10K+ user can see it

Comment: ahah @BryanChen  - so that means you can see it! What about it was so bad?

Comment: it just an ads for a company

Comment: mmm surely that is subjective that it is just an ad. Is there evidence to link the poster + the site together? It could be a programmer recommending a tool they found helpful. I would write a similar answer to recommend EPPPlus for creating excel spreadsheets for example, but I have no affiliation with the product.

Comment: oo I just found this. +1! [feature request for Invalid Audit button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/151967)

Comment: Related MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/262723.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this certainly isn't hazing. The system automatically chooses audits from all posts based on the types of actions that were taken on them. Answers that have been upvoted in a short span of time, and are fairly recent, are chosen for "good" audits. Answers that were downvoted quite a bit, flagged, or deleted are chosen for "bad" audits.

The link that is given to you shows the last audit that you failed. There has been [a proposal presented on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed) to show the deleted answer to people who don't have enough reputation to see it through the audit history, but this hasn't been implemented yet.