# A review ban that lets me confused about good question and highly upvoted question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

Several minutes ago I received a review ban:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently, see: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21733095.
>
> Come back in 4 days to continue reviewing.

In my opinion, if **just look at the question without the answer**, this question doesn't seem a good question. With a simple [Google search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+ERR%21+404+Not+Found%3A+event-stream), a discussion in GitHub that [gave a result](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/698#issuecomment-443268808) **before** when this question is asked can be found easily, which indicates that this question didn't show an effort for solving question, I think. That's why I tried to downvote it. Then I was banned.

Showed this current-event question from a 11k+ asker has 17 upvotes, with a 32 upvotes self-accepted answer, I tried to search from MSO, and found some conclusions: [Answers that have been upvoted in a short span of time, and are fairly recent, are chosen for "good" audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286528/9035237), though [no system is perfect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267197/9035237).

So what I want to ask is: The reason why this question is "good", is just the high upvote, or due to its good-enough quality? How can I prevent such audit failure in the future?

After all, I can't see the really well-researched self answer during reviewing.

Comment: It's not just the number of up votes, it's that no one had down voted the question. It's gotten 2 down votes now so it will no longer be chosen as an audit.

Comment: There is not much signal in just one failed audit, even though a post with 17 helpful votes ought to be easy.  If you want real help then focus a bit on all the other audits you failed.

Comment: @BSMP I am 3 accept or 4 upvote away from seeing vote :-) Thank you for tell me that.

Comment: You were not alone. [6 out of the 7 audits on that post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53578201/timeline) were failed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You got *burned* on this one.

So here's the deal - that particular package was compromised, and a hacker could use this as a way to mine Bitcoin.  This was promptly yanked, as the [answer on the question explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578285/1079354).

Sans context, you would ***never*** have known what this question was looking at.  You did the review in the right way and got punished for it, which is...unfortunate.

The question *has* value since maintainers may wake up to discover an NPM dependency has suddenly disappeared on them and may be looking for the reasons why.  In spite of the *very* good reason, there are still a lot of people out there who don't keep up with this kind of information and would be surprised by it.

Audits do this sometimes in that they give us what seem to be straightforward audit questions but have more nuance than the actual window provides for us.  Flag for a moderator to look into this case and reference this Meta question and *hopefully* your ban will get lifted.

<sup>Although it doesn't take just *one* failed audit to get an audit ban...but I'd call Mulligan on *this* one.</sup>

Comment: "The question has value since maintainers may wake up to discover an NPM dependency has suddenly disappeared on them and may be looking for the reasons why. In spite of the very good reason, there are still a lot of people out there who don't keep up with this kind of information and would be surprised by it." But even before this question was asked you could just search on the error message, and see a good explanation of the problem and a description of what to do about it as the top result (which the SO question itself references).  Thus the question was poorly researched.

Comment: @Servy That's one of the reason why I downvote that question. Additionally, I don't know whether it is necessary that _many_ breaking technical news should be reflected on SO like this.

Comment: @Servy:  This is why I mention that the review was likely done correctly - seeing that same question sans context I too would've likely voted to close it - but *in* context, the question and answer is greater than the sum of its parts.  It's also dominating the Google results list, since I can't really find *useful* info in the first few results except a handful of GitHub posts.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not seeing how  *in context* the question is useful though.  You're saying that you can't find any useful information on the topic *except for some posts that describe the exact problem and what to do about it, which are useful* (at also rank above it on Google, for the record).  That post is just repeating what those other sources are already saying.  Creating an SO post to just repeat the information already posted *and readily accessible* elsewhere seems like the epitomy of a "not well researched" and "not useful" post.

Comment: @Makoto Oh, yes. Since the result lies in the very bottom in the GitHub post (which is the first search result), an anxious developer may ignore it and dive into other search result (may found nearly nothing on how to solve this issue **quickly**, if there isn't **that** SO question and answer).

Comment: @GenoChen:  Yes, this is precisely my point.  Skimming across these articles doesn't give me much closure, but reading the SO answer gives me *tons* of closure.

Comment: I upvoted the question itself because it is helpful, but you are right, this is a bad audit. I voted on question quality itself, not on audit suitability. Figuring out audit suitability belongs to the mods.

Answer (score -9):

Before closing the question as "why isn't this code working" offtopic the context should be known (could be such question interesting for anybody else?). Actually, Meta's consensus is not only one important metainformation to evaluate the content. Surprise.

What is really unpleasant that we can't predict Meta's decision. Highly possible scenario is that the question will be closed  and then reopened again.

During review I would skip it.

Comment: Skipping it is a bad choice.  Sans context the action was appropriate.

Comment: I can't believe no one has offered to forbid the skip button yet...

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij Skip means "I'm not certain" (which is totally ok). But the linked question - without the context - is indeed **awful**. The title is only the raw error message (strike one), context given is *"I am trying to deploy my project and I'm suddenly getting this error."* (whoa, don't give us that many details; strike two), followed - by the raw error message again (strike three, out)

Comment: This was how you explained to yourself why you have **not** downvoted or flaged it?